# Gradle Libraries Conflict

Tags: android, gradle

I'm having a conflict in libraries and failing to resolve it and the error is always

Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRequestDirector;

The project compiles and runs if I don't implement the jackson2 and Robospice libraries, however, I need so what to do.

here's my gradle

```
dependencies {


    implementation files('libs/speedchecker-android-sdk-1.3.jar')


    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:2.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    implementation('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0') {
        exclude module: 'commons-io' 
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax'
    }
    implementation('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-google-http-client:1.4.14') {
        exclude module: 'commons-io'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
    }
}
```

After trying for several hours, I noticed that the conflict is resulting from the following 3 (the two libraries came with the speed test jar file library when i bought it, so after upgrading the build tools the conflict occurred)

```
implementation files('libs/speedchecker-android-sdk-1.3.jar')

implementation('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io' 
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax'
}

implementation('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-google-http-client:1.4.14') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change gradle.property and multidexenable= true;

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and also include

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: did you rebuild project also after that and clean?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you're mixing libraries that shouldn't be mixed

looking at your build file these libraries are conflicting:

1. firebase contains both versions `16.0.1` and `17.1.0` which are conflicting and;
2. there are dependencies to both firebase and gcm (version `15.0.1` ) which are also conflicting

get rid of those and it should build without issues

Comment: no this is not the case, since in all the new versions it's like this

Comment: try me, I am not sure what "all the new versions" means but gcm and auth via gms are dead

Comment: what about the different firebase dependencies?